# Data in a CSV file pushed/sent over to Google Charts

Tags: bash, csv-simple, graph

I have a CSV file, where the accumulated data is as such (just a snippet):

```
...
20150327,TEST-MACHINE-091,9,10
20150327,TEST-MACHINE-092,2,7
20150327,TEST-MACHINE-093,1,4
20150328,TEST-MACHINE-091,9,20
20150329,DIFFERENT-TEST-MACHINE-091,53546,53567
20150329,TEST-MACHINE-092,12,37
...
```

To explain the data:

```
DATE,MACHINES-UNIQUE-NAME,DAILY_OPERATION_HOURS,ACCUMULATED_OPERATION_HOURS
```

I would like to write a script where this data is sent off to Google Charts to be drawn. At the end I would like to see something like this:

[image]

I would like to have this *n* times as there are *n* `test-machines`. I don't know how this could be done.

**Q:** How can I write a code where I can send the aforementioned data off to Google Charts to get [such a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBDYI.png)?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to copy the data into a Google Spreadsheets document and do your thing in there, you have to see the Google Chart API (https://developers.google.com/chart/) or the Google Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/). There are bindings for a lot of languages and even a tutorial using curl.